# Formatting HTML code in sublime3, Press Ctrl+Shift+F hot key，< will replace &lt;

Tags: html

if a html is

```html
<p>&lt;head&gt;</p>
```

Press Ctrl+Shift+F hot key:Becoming below

```
<p><head></p>
```

I want to keep not changing after I press this hot key

```html
 &lt
```

how to resolve this question?

Answer (score 0):

try code using

```html
<pre>
```

tag

like

```html
<pre>&lt;head&gt;</pre>
```

so please try this

```html
<pre>&amp;lt;head&amp;gt;</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean。using pre Tag of course .but your browser will show &lt，not show <. My purpose  is that &lt will show &lt in sublime3 and will show < in browser.